# Javascript problem with Hyperlink to Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, button, mobile, hyperlink

I created a button that I want to send the user to the MercadoLibre Reviews section, however, when I execute it it asks for authorization, but it does not send the user to the correct section.

On the web it works ok, but on mobile no.

You shouldn't have any problem going to the opinions section.

I also tried window.open// and window.location.href but that doesn't work either.

[image]

```html
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Valoración de Experiencia de Compra en Universal Importaciones</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"> <!-- Agregar Font Awesome para íconos de estrella -->
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #006bd6; /* Fondo azul */
        color: #FFFFFF; /* Texto blanco */
    }
    h1, h2, h3 {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    #votacion {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .stars {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Cambiar la dirección de las estrellas */
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .stars input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
    .stars label {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: color 0.3s;
    }
    .stars label:hover,
    .stars input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
        color: #ffd700; /* Color de estrella seleccionada */
    }
    #feedback-box {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #feedback-box textarea {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 5px; /* Redondear bordes de la textarea */
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #feedback-box button {
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #ff03a7; /* Color del botón */
        color: #FFFFFF; /* Texto blanco */
        font-size: 14px; /* Tamaño del texto */
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px; /* Redondear bordes del botón */
    }
    #mensaje-final {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footer p {
        margin: 5px;
    }
    #footer a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    #footer a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #footer .icons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .stars label {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        #feedback-box textarea {
            width: 90%;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Valoración de Experiencia de Compra en Universal Importaciones</h1>

<div id="votacion">
    <h2>¿Qué Calificación le pondrías a tu Producto?</h2>
    <div class="stars">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="star5"><label for="star5"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="star4"><label for="star4"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="star3"><label for="star3"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="star2"><label for="star2"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="star1"><label for="star1"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="feedback-box" style="display: none;">
    <h3>¿Cuéntanos que le faltó al producto para tener una Mejor Calificación?</h3>
    <textarea id="feedback" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="enviarFeedback()">Enviar</button>
</div>

<div id="mensaje-final" style="display: none;">
    <p style="color: black;">Agradecemos tu respuesta, estamos en la búsqueda de mejorar tu experiencia de compra y tus comentarios son muy importantes para nosotros.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Barrio Cordón: <i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i> Mercedes 1879 esq. Fernández Crespo.</p>
    <p><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Lunes a viernes de 09:00 a 18:00 hs. Sábados de 9:00 a 12:30 hs.</p>
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="https://wa.me/59892478000"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> WhatsApp</a>
        <a href="mailto:contacto@ortopediauniversal.com.uy"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Email</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js"></script> <!-- Agregar script de Font Awesome -->
<script>
    const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.stars input[type="radio"]');
    const feedbackBox = document.getElementById('feedback-box');
    const mensajeFinal = document.getElementById('mensaje-final');

stars.forEach(star => {
    star.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (this.value <= 3) {
            feedbackBox.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            // Abrir el enlace en una nueva pestaña del navegador
            window.location.href = 'https://www.mercadolibre.com.uy/my-reviews';
        }
    });
});
    function enviarFeedback() {
        const feedback = document.getElementById('feedback').value;
        // Aquí puedes agregar la lógica para enviar el feedback por correo electrónico
        mensajeFinal.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is star? Please add relevant html

Comment: The star is like a button, if it has 3 or less stars that the person selects performs an action, if they select 4 or more it redirects them to the website that can be seen there @mplungjan

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please [edit] and make it a [mcve]

Comment: Done! @mplungjan In the web version it redirects ok, but in the mobile version it doesn't!

Comment: @mplungjan you can download the app of MercadoLibre on PlayStore/AppStore and create and account and try if in the mobile redirects you well.